# Prove that if a pentagon has each diagonal parallel to the opposite side, then it is regular.

Tags: polygons, plane-geometry

Given a generic pentagon (you don't know anything about sides or angles), if each diagonal is parallel to the opposite side, then the pentagon is regular.

AB is parallel to EC, BC to AD and so on...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider an irregular pentagon with the following vertices:

$(0, 0),\; (1, 0),\; (0, 1),\; (1, \phi),\; (\phi, 1)$

where$\; \phi = \frac{\sqrt5 + 1
}{2}$

[image: Image of the Pentagon from MS Paint]

Each of its diagonals is parallel to one of the pentagon's sides, which is a contradiction to the original statement.